# Django rest framework conditionally required fields

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I would like to write a [drf validator](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/validators/#optional-fields) that will mark a field as required based on the value of an other field.
For example:

```
class MySerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    has_children = fields.BooleanField()
    nb_childs = fields.IntegerField(min_value=1, validators=[RequiredIf(field='has_children', value=True)], required=False)
```

At first i believed the [class based validator](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/validators/#class-based) was the way to do it, by retrieving the value of 'has_children' with a method like this:

```
def set_context(self, serializer_field):
    print serializer_field.parent.initial_data
```

but the 'initial_data' is not set. Any clue?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Have a look [here in the DRF documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#object-level-validation)

Basically, to do object-level validation, you need to override the Serializer's `validate(self, data)` method, do your validation using the `data` parameter's value (this is the serializer's state provided as a `dict` to validate) then raise a `ValidationError` if anything is wrong.

If you need to raise an error for a specific field, then you can pass a dictionary as the parameter to the `ValidationError` constructor:

```
raise ValidationError({'yourfield': ['Your message']})
```

Comment: Sorry but it's not what i asked for, I want a Validator. overriding validate wont do since the ValidationError will not be associated with the field.

Comment: You can raise field-level errors by passing a dictionary in the `ValidationError` constructor: `raise ValidationError({'yourfield': ['Error message']})`

Comment: sorry i didn't know about that.  That should work for me, thanks

Answer (score 8):

*I am using several mixins for that purpose, which are changing **field**.**required** attribute and as result **error validation messages** are **generated automatically by DRF***

**PerFieldMixin**

```
class ConditionalRequiredPerFieldMixin:
"""Allows to use serializer methods to allow change field is required or not"""

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    for field_name, field in self.fields.items():
        method_name = f'is_{field_name}_required'
        if hasattr(self, method_name):
            field.required = getattr(self, method_name)()
```

**How to use PerFieldMixin**

```
class MySerializer(ConditionalRequiredPerFieldMixin, serializers.ModelSerializer):
    subject_id = serializers.CharField(max_length=128, min_length=3, required=False)

    def is_subject_id_required(self):
        study = self.context['study']
        return not study.is_community_study
```

**PerActionMixin**

```
class ActionRequiredFieldsMixin:
    """Required fields per DRF action
    Example:
    PER_ACTION_REQUIRED_FIELDS = {
        'update': ['notes']
    }
    """
    PER_ACTION_REQUIRED_FIELDS = None

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.context.get('view'):
            action = self.context['view'].action
            required_fields = (self.PER_ACTION_REQUIRED_FIELDS or {}).get(action)
            if required_fields:
                for field_name in required_fields:
                    self.fields[field_name].required = True
```

**How to use PerActionMixin**

see docstrings, for action == update (ie PUT request) - field "notes" will be required)

Comment: I would like to know how you get self.context['study'] in the example. For me this is giving a KeyError even on GET requests. I think it should be coming from either data or cleaned_data, right?

Comment: You could pass some extra data (context) during serializer initialization that would later be available inside this serializer. DRF docs: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#including-extra-context